# How to create a new table without duplicates in a field, based on a table that has duplicates in this field?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, duplicates

How do I create a new table in Access without duplicates in the PROD_ID field based on a table that has duplicates in this field?

I would like a table like this:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ PROD_ID ║ ATC_COD_1 ║ ATC_COD_2 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║      65 ║ D01AC02   ║ D10AE01   ║
║      71 ║ R01BA52   ║ R06AX07   ║
║     101 ║ N02BE51   ║ M03BX05   ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Note: PROD_ID; ATC_COD_1 and ATC_COD_2 are the field names.

Starting with table like this:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ PROD_ID ║ ATC_COD ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║      65 ║ D01AC02 ║
║      65 ║ D10AE01 ║
║      71 ║ R01BA52 ║
║      71 ║ R06AX07 ║
║     101 ║ N02BE51 ║
║     101 ║ M03BX05 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

Note: PROD_ID; ATC_COD are the field names.

There always will be only two records for each PROD_ID and I don't need any criteria.

Comment: Will there always be two records for each `PROD_ID` in your original table or is there a variable number of them? Things get pretty complicated in the latter case. Also do you care which one will be `ATC_COD_1` and which will be `ATC_COD_2` and if yes what is the criteria?

Comment: SunKnight0 Thank You, There always will be only two records for each PROD_ID and I don't need any critéria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select PROD_ID,
       min(ATC_COD) as ATC_COD_1,
       if(min(ATC_COD) <> max(ATC_COD), max(ATC_COD), null) as ATC_COD_2 
from t
group by PROD_ID
```

Comment: I would also consider the use of `first` and `last` maybe as min would be the mininum value rather than the first in the table.

Comment: If Will not be there always two records for each PROD_ID and I dont care which one will be ATC_COD_1; ATC_COD_2; ATC_COD_3; etc , do you have any solution ?